# long to wide - converting one column (with multiple measures) into a pair of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2

I have been trying to reshape a clustered-structure long dataset to wide format: within each cluster, the wide format will have two pairings of columns representing the long format measure.

Here's an example of the long format:

```
set.seed(20190419)
   dt1<-data.frame(
     id=sample(1:10),
     fam=c(rep(c('a','b'),each=3),rep(c('d'),each=4)),
     value=rnorm(10))

dt1
```

> id is the unique variable for each individual, fam is the clustering id (family id), and value is the measure.

Instead of having 1 row and 4 columns representing values of each member within the family, I would like the wide format to have multiple rows with 2 columns showing pairs of family member's value. For example, with a family of size 3, the wide format will include 3 rows indicating values from member 1-2, 1-3, 2-3.

And here's the ideal wide format:

[wide format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLUK3.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a self-join:

```
dt1 %>% left_join(dt1, by = "fam") %>%
  filter(id.x < id.y)
#    id.x fam    value.x id.y    value.y
# 1     1   a  0.1231950    2  0.1090744
# 2     1   a  0.1231950    6  0.6753560
# 3     2   a  0.1090744    6  0.6753560
# 4     5   b  1.2385780    7  0.7440739
# 5     5   b  1.2385780   10  2.4763114
# 6     7   b  0.7440739   10  2.4763114
# 7     3   d -2.3296467    8  0.1370525
# 8     3   d -2.3296467    4 -0.5790046
# 9     3   d -2.3296467    9  0.3267871
# 10    8   d  0.1370525    9  0.3267871
# 11    4   d -0.5790046    8  0.1370525
# 12    4   d -0.5790046    9  0.3267871
```

Comment: @akrun that has a more potential to blow up with bigger data if there are many many small `fam`s. I like this better because at least we can restrict the `by = "fam"` prior to filtering.